# SSRS : Not able to see all stack charts in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a Stack Chart in SSRS. I have associated the dataset successfully, but somehow I am not able to see all the values in my report. Please see the attached images.

[image: chart one]

But on Preview I am only seeing few values

[image: chart two]

Comment: I am not able to see the topmost bar (bar above red) in my preview although the expression written for it brings a valid value. Because that expression i am using in other reports as well.

Comment: Could be caused by the sum of a null value: `SUM(ISNULL(Corp_Stnd, 0))` Also why do you have Corp Stnd twice?